# Can I build entities in Symfony2 from an SQL DB schema?

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an existing db modeled acording to my bussiness logic and i want to build up symfony2 entities from this db model. Is it possible?

Here there are some facts:

- The reason why i start with the db doesn't mind. I wanna know if is it possible what i asked.
- My db is MySql

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can !

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html
- http://blog.alterphp.com/2011/06/some-tips-for-doctrine2-entities.html

There is a tool (not free but with 30 days trial) that may interest you : http://www.www.skipper18.com

Comment: Thank you!! Sincerely I was unable to find it out!